# Maximum planar subgraph problem

Tags: graphs, planar-graphs, subgraphs

Given a graph G I want to find the maximum planar subgraph which is a grid graph.
(Because the nodes of this subgraph represent points on a grid).

Is there any library in python for finding the maximum planar subgraph?

Is there some way how to implement these constraints for the grid graph?

Edit: As I understood I am looking for the maximum planar subgraph which is at most 4-connected and at least 2-connected

Comment: Induced subgraph? What about the $n \times 1$ subgraph?

Comment: Are you allowed to delete edges, or only vertices?

Comment: Check out the crossing number of a graph.

Comment: PS, the maximum planar subgraph problem is NP-hard.

Comment: It is the opposite of an induced subgraph - i am not allowed to delete vertices, only edges. The crossing number should go to zero. I know - MSP is NP hard, but isnt there any approximation?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there are any implementations for the algorithms you are looking for.

The problem, also known as *Planar Edge Deletion*, *Edge Planarization*, *Graph Planarization*, or sometimes *Minimum Planarization*, is NP-complete and was shown in 2007 to be fixed-parameter tractable (for every *fixed* number of edges you want to delete, there is a "linear time algorithm" for the problem).  However, the algorithm is extremely non-trivial and rely on deep mathematical results.

* K. Kawarabayashi and B.A. Reed. Computing crossing number in linear time. In: Proc. STOC 2007, 382—390.

Comment: Where is here the connection to the grid graph (3 or 4 connected graph)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question about your particular problem, but you can find theory for a related problem involving grids by searching for "bidimensionality".

It's the idea that every graph is either low treewidth or contains a large grid minor which makes it possible to get solution in polynomial time.

See Section 3 in [Beyond Planar Graphs](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Ezdvir/apx11slides/erik-scribe.pdf) presentation by DeMaine.
Also this is mentioned in Section 1 of [Width parameters beyond tree-width and their applications](https://www.fi.muni.cz/%7Ehlineny/plain/papers/Wmain.pdf), which is a good tutorial for the basics needed to understand bidimensionality results.

Comment: Minors and subgraphs are very different, though. Also, you don't actually find a grid minor when applying bidimensionality, you only conclude that it exists and then you return a correct answer based on that knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, edited the post

Comment: Not sure yet this will help, but I appreciate your help:)